# undefined method `user_model' for nil:NilClass IN FIREFOX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox

I am having a Strange problem w/ Firefox. My app runs in rspec, and Safari and Chrome but abends in Firefox with

```
undefined method `user_model' for nil:NilClass
```

Why would an application level error occur based on which browser is rendering?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your session cookie is caching a reference to an object that has been deleted in your database. (Which is now nil, but you're trying to get at its user_model.) This can happen if you are using your application, delete your database, and then try to go back to using your application.

Clearing your cookies should fix it (if this is the problem).

ETA: (You probably only need to delete the default rails session cookie, which is usually named _appname_session.)